# Try to make a column of named school classes: 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 2A, 2B in one column using just one-cell formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I challenged myself and make a formula that produces a column of class names.
My goal was to make it in one cell and without repeating the same commands.
I failed.
My best result is a column of commands that makes an array and then this array is flattened.
I believe it can be done. I tried more nested arrayformulas but with no good result.
Do anyone have a time to try this exercise?
I think using a script is unsporty here. ;-)

Array is made using this formula for each row (19 to 26):

```
=ArrayFormula(sequence(1;B5;A5;0)&CHAR(sequence(1;B5;65;1)))
```

Then I flatten it and remove empty cells:

```
=query(flatten(A19:I26);"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

[image]

Here is my playground:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1udZ1NAkv1EmIAXlCZz_CMCK6wkG2U-JSklM3fc7UJP8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(A5:A12&"×"; B5:B12); "×")&
 TRANSPOSE(CHAR(ROW(65:90)))); 
 "where Col1 matches '^\d+.'"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now I have some food for my thought analyzing your formula!